# JMeter End to End Report for each Thread in Test Plan

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to Understand JMeter reports and kind of Confused or rather stuck at one place. After building script i am able to capture response time for each step under my Main Thread but when i am looking for Overall time i don't see any report for this.

```
Scenario/Steps in Thread -
1 - Submit Quote Request
2 - Read the Response
3 - Create New Request and Submit Request
4 - Check the Status and Until Status says complete continue checking in While Controller.
```

If you look at above scenario i have 4 steps and i am able to capture the time for each step, but i am looking for Overall time entire thread took. As i have 3 different thread in my Test plan i want to compare them with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to figure it out, if you put all 4 step under transaction Controller. Then at the end of execution you will get the Average response time for transaction Controller under Aggregate Report.